# How to build .Net MAUI app referencing a standard .Net 6 Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I have a standard C# class library that's used for a lot of different projects, and I'd like to use it as a project reference in .Net MAUI. I've put this class library in the same solution as .NET MAUI. When I run the GUI from the VS debugger the app works fine, however when I try to publish it I get the error:
Metadata file '..\bin\Release\net6.0\win10-x64\myclasslibrary.dll' could not be found

In fact, my class library is located at: '..\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\myclasslibrary.dll'

How do I tell the .Net MAUI publish to look within the "win-x64" folder instead of "win10-x64"? Or alternatively how do I tell my class library to also compile to the win10-x64 folder as well? I've tried adding additional frameworks such as .net6-windows however the class library still isn't generating the win10-x64 folder, only the win-x64 one.

**Update:**

Here are the .csproj files for both my normal .net6 class library, and the MAUI project -

Standard .NET6  Class Library Project .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="NSec.Cryptography" Version="22.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

MAUI Project .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyMAUIApp_GUI</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>MyMAUIApp-GUI</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.MyMAUIApp_gui</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>00A85426-C72C-48BC-A656-26F0DD2470E7</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <DefaultLanguage>en</DefaultLanguage>
    <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>False</AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>
    <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>MyMAUIApp-GUI_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
    <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA256</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
  <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
    <MauiImage Include="wwwroot\images\negative.svg" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <RazorComponent Include="Components\TxAddressBlock.razor" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\MSIX-win10-x642.pubxml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMAUIApp\ClassLibrary.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To confirm I added the class library to the MAUI project in VS2022 by right clicking the project, selecting Add > Project Reference, and selecting the .csproj file for the class library

Comment: How have you referenced the class library? Are you able to reproduce this in a brand new solution, so you could post the project file for the class library and the relevant part of the project file for MAUI?

Comment: Check if do you have if DEBUG anywhere in your code?

Comment: If you're building the library together with your MAUI project (directly from source), you should use a ProjectReference, not a binary reference. Project references link to the project file (csproj) not the dll and automatically figure out the correct paths.

Comment: hi @Jon Skeet I've updated my question with the information requested. I've created a new solution, simply adding the class library as a reference, and the same problem is encountered from my .net MAUI app

Comment: Why does your class library have runtime identifiers in the project file? That may well be the problem. Either removing them entirely or adding win10-x64 might solve it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Amazing! Commenting out the RuntimeIdentifier fixed it! Am a huge fan of your book and a great honour to have you personally solve this problem, thank you! I'm not sure how that tag got there and caused the problems it did? Nevertheless, all is good now!