# How to build .Net MAUI app referencing a standard .Net 6 projects?

Tags: maui

My .net Maui is in net7.0 and refers to the other projects within the same solution in net6.0

```
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'XXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

This is a project file for net6.0 projects

```
  <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
<AnalysisLevel>6.0-all</AnalysisLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is a project file for net7.0 .net maui project

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>

    <!-- Assembly info -->
    <Title> project title </Title>
    <Company>xyz  Technologies</Company>
    <Product>xyz product </Product>
    <Copyright>Copyright xyz</Copyright>

    <!-- MAUI specific assembly info -->
    <ApplicationTitle> app title </ApplicationTitle>
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.project</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>de55addd-a0f9-4c7f-a6d1-81e9937bdab5</ApplicationIdGuid>
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
    <WindowsPackageType Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">None</WindowsPackageType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I read through the solution from this post but nothing helped.

[How to build .Net MAUI app referencing a standard .Net 6 Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752792/how-to-build-net-maui-app-referencing-a-standard-net-6-class-library)

Comment: Did you want to use the projects targeted on the .net6 in the .net7 environment? First, you can make sure if the projects can run in the .net7. Second, you can try to delete the "obj" folder and then rebuild it.